# Is there a way to override android default incoming call screen?

Tags: android

I am creating an android game. I don't want user to be distracted by the incoming call screen. So when a call comes I want to give user a button and on clicking the button it would take him to default call screen. I know how to detect the incoming call. But the challenge is to override the default call screen.

Comment: Have a look at these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001725/intercept-the-androids-os-incoming-call-screen-and-replace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913789/androidoverride-incoming-call-screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210476/override-incoming-call-screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android

Comment: I tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869314/can-an-activity-receive-an-unordered-broadcastincoming-call-intent-before-syst but it was not working. The app crashes with error as no activity to handle intent. I think android.intent.action.ANSWER is the systems activity. I tried it on Android 6.0